# Is it possible to have hyphens in a yaml key for use in my I18n en.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, rails-i18n

For example :

```
en:
  foobar-does-not-work: 'This is my value'
```

Then if I do :

```
t(foobar-does-not-work) # => returns nil
```

This will not parse in Ruby's yml. Is there some way to make it work though? My keys are based on URL's which have dashes ( `-` ) in them.

Comment: I think using dashes in a key is allowed and should not give problems. Are you sure it's the dashes?

Comment: @zwippie I'm positive. Ruby doesn't allow it.

Comment: Well I tried it and my Ruby (version) does allow it. What Ruby version are you on?

Comment: @zwippie My apologies! It does seem to work in raw ruby. I guess my case is that it doesn't work when parsing through my en.yml ( Il8n file ). Updated my question

Comment: You don’t have quotes around the string. Is this just a typo (since you say it returns nil rather than a syntax error)?

Answer (score 5):

Which version of ruby are you using? Can you show us your code and the error?

It works for me:

```
> require 'yaml'
> YAML.load_file('foo.yml')
{"en"=>{"foobar-does-not-work"=>"This is my value"}}
```

And it works when I add it to my en.yml:

```
> I18n.t('foobar-does-not-work')
=> "This is my value"
```

Have you checked the value of I18n.locale?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Yes it does seem to work in console like your example. But for some reason when I do it through my en.yml ( Il8n file ), it won't load. Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Clearly there is an underlying problem that needs to be ferreted out. There is very good tool which analyzes your i18n YAML as the Rails app, which I have found extremely helpful in debug.

Install and run this gem i18n-tasks: https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks.

To create a comprehensive report of the your i18n components:

```
$ i18n-tasks health
```

From their spec:

```
This gem analyses code statically for key usages, such as I18n.t('some.key'), in order to:

Report keys that are missing or unused.
Pre-fill missing keys, optionally from Google Translate.
Remove unused keys.
Thus addressing the two main problems of i18n gem design:

Missing keys only blow up at runtime.
Keys no longer in use may accumulate and introduce overhead, without you knowing it.
```

---

I'm not sure the gem was intended to be used as an i18n debug tool, but I  have found it to be useful for debugging hard to find problems in i18n.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just using the wrong key when calling the `t` method.  Remove 'en' from the key. It should be:

```
t('foobar-does-not-work')
```

Comment: Super good point. I just checked my code, and I realized I only included that in the example. It still doesn't seem to work even with the en removed